# Python, get the value of self.request.get() inside __init__

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I wanted to get the values of `self.request.get('foo')` and etal everytime I create an instance of a class, so I decided to use `__init__` constructor. Here's my code:

```
class archive(handler):
    d = dict(title='',author= '')

    def __init__(self):
        self.d['title'] = self.request.get('title')
        self.d['author'] = self.request.get('author')

class compose(handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('compose.html')

    def post(self):
        a = archive()
```

My purpose is, to get rid the repetition of:

```
title = self.request.get('title')
author = self.request.get('author')
```

in every `def post(self)`. But the problem is I get a `NoneType` error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Obviously, `self.request.get('title')` returned None. I am just new with Python and Google Appengine.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to fix the problem:

```
class Archive(object):
    d = dict(title='',author= '')

    def load_d(self):
        r = webapp2.get_request()

        self.d['title'] = r.get('title')
        self.d['author'] = r.get('author')

class Compose(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('compose.html')

    def post(self):
        a = Archive()
        a.load_d()
```

Comment: Your code may work, but here's a few tips, if I may. 1) class names should begin with a capital letter. 2) methods beginning with the word "get" usually imply that they return something. In your case, it's not returning anything. 3) 'd' is initialized as a class variable, but is referred to with self. This is probably fine for your code, but the code archive.d is valid, and will return the last value assigned to d, therefore potentially leaking data. If you instead declared d within the get_request method, and return it at the end, you would also make your get more meaningful

Comment: 4) why is get_request defined in it's own class? You could alternatively define it either in the Compose class, or in a base class from which Compose inherits from. In both scenarios, you wouldn't need to pass in the self.request param, as it would still be in scope. 5) i am not sure of the usefulness of the get_request method in the first place - you are taking data from the request and putting it in a dictionary - if you ever want to use that data you still need to get them from the dictionary?

Comment: @GwynHowell, 1) In my actual implementation of code, all Class names begin with capital letter, sorry for not using it. 2) You're right, maybe I should rename it something like "keep" or "hold" just to apply proper usage of names. 3) Actually, I intended to keep those data in dictionary for some other related transactions (i.e. validations, creating custom key, etc.).

Comment: @GwynHowell 4) I defined `get_request` on the Class Archive since many classes and methods will also be accessing it (containing current data from request). 5) "if you ever want to use that data you still need to get them from the dictionary?" -Yes, if you have a better suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use webapp2.

Your init overrides the init of the webapp2 request handler (super). You can read in the webapp2 docs how to to this:

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-init

Take care when you use variables (self.variable) because you can also override variables of the request handler. You can use the request registry.

Comment: Yes, I'm using webapp2. Thanks for reminding me about (self.variables), you're right (my bad). By the way, I got it working now. I've changed my structure, instead of using `__init__`, I replaced it with `@staticmethod` named `get_request(r)` and the instance object now become `a.get_request(self.request)`. I also replaced the `(handler)` parameter with `(object)` since I don't need `RequestHandler` on archive class anyway. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can also use request = webapp2.get_request() to get the request without passing is as an arg.

Comment: I find your suggestion above is much more convenient. I'll update my post. Thank you so much.